# Check if individual values from a df are within another. If they are, do x, otherwise do y

Tags: r

I'm doing a sticker book project.

I generate a pack of stickers via this code:

```
for (stickers in 1:1){
  newstickers <- c(sample(1:568, 5, replace = TRUE))
  newstickers <- data.frame(newstickers)
  print(newstickers) #just to check it worked
}
```

which gives me the following as an example:

```
  newstickers
1         335
2         555
3         460
4         428
5         339
```

I now want to essentially run through these 5 stickers and check whether they appear in my 'Sticker Book'. If they do (they're duplicates) so add them to a 'Swaps Collection'. If they don't (they're new/unique stickers) so I want to add these to my 'Sticker Book' df.

I thought something like this would work but it's either not the correct option or isn't quite formatted correctly (still very much a beginner!)

```
for (sticker in 1:nrow(newstickers)) {
  if(sticker %in% StickerAlbum) {
    SwapsCollection <- rbind.fill(SwapsCollection, data.frame(sticker))
  } else {
    StickerAlbum <- rbind.fill(StickerAlbum, data.frame(sticker)) 
  }
}
```

Expected Output

When run the first time the Sticker Book is empty so all 5 values should be added

```
> StickerAlbum
   sticker
1        335
2        555
3        460
4        428
5        339
```

However when I generate a second pack of stickers, say 335, 555, 1, 2, 3

The numbers 335 and 555 are duplicates so should be added to Swaps Collection and the new Sticker Book would look like

```
> StickerAlbum
   sticker
1        335
2        555
3        460
4        428
5        339
6         1
7         2
8         3

> SwapsCollection
   sticker
1        335
2        555
```

Comment: Your `if` condition may be wrong because `%in%` works with vector, while `StickerAlbum` is a data.frame

Comment: Additonally, `for(sticker in1:nrow(newstickers))` will not get the actual sticker column. you may want

`for(sticker in newstickers$newstickers)`.

Comment: @JustinLandis - This has fixed getting the actual stickers part. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a few things you could probably improve upon.

First you should try and normalize what your `data.frame` columns are called. Maybe they should just be a single column with a name `stickers`

e.i.

```
for (stickers in 1:1){
  newstickers <- c(sample(1:568, 5, replace = TRUE))
  newstickers <- data.frame(stickers = newstickers)
  print(newstickers) #just to check it worked
}
```

to be honest, this for statement is redundant since you don't use "stickers" anywhere within the curly braces.

next as I said in my comment, you will get consistency when working with the variable names.

```
#assuming StickerAlbum is also a data.frame with 
#a "stickers" column

#loop through newstickers$stickers and assign each
#value to sticker
for (sticker in newstickers$stickers) { 

  #compare sticker to those values inside
  #StickerAlbum$stickers vector.
  if(sticker %in% StickerAlbum$stickers) {
    SwapsCollection <- rbind.fill(
       SwapsCollection, 
       data.frame(stickers = sticker)
      )
  } else {
    StickerAlbum <- rbind.fill(
       StickerAlbum, 
       data.frame(stickers = sticker)
      ) 
 }
}
```

Comment: You Sir, are a hero. Seems to work bang on with what I'm after.

Thank you for the lesson within too. As a beginner, very useful help!